# How to Jquery foreach in the if controle

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop

I'm returning an array. I don't want to ahve same elements. So how I make a if control?

```
    $.each(data, function(v, k) {
        if ( ) {
            // İşlem
        }

    });


      headers.forEach(function (header, i) {

                    if (  ) { // controle ??? 



                     }
       });
```

I don't want another same element in array? .

Comment: where is data ? or where is headers ?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
var result = []; // result array without duplicate
$.each(data, function(v, k) {
   if ($.inArray(k, result) == -1) result.push(k);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function to get distinct elements in an array:

```
function getDistinctArray(arr) {
    var compareArray = new Array();
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        for (i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
            if (compareArray.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
                compareArray.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return compareArray;
}
```

You can pass the final array to this function before returning the array.